# Does what happened to Jon Snow make him immune to White Walkers?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* season six, Jon Snow was brought back to life by Melisandre using her magic.

With this being said, is there any chance this action makes him immune to White Walkers?

She used the power that was given to her by her Lord of Light, and as we know White Walkers are afraid of the fire.

Comment: Answer is : Nobody knows.

Comment: FYI, Wights may be afraid of fire, however the White Walkers are not as seen in the Hold the Door episode.

Comment: @kuhl : The White Walkers ARE seen in the Hold the Door episode. They are even walking through the fire that the Children of the Forest set at the cavern's entrance.

Comment: @Nico They are seen in that episode, they are not [afraid of fire] as seen in that episode.  I believe we're in agreement on this one.

Comment: @Kuhl and Nico, it's the higher up White Walkers and the Night King who can walk through the fire. Lesser wights can't.

Comment: @TheAnathema thanks for recapping my comment. :)

Comment: Well it's not that they're just afraid. They can't or they will "die."

Comment: How can you came up with this theory. It's amazing. Never thought of it before.

Comment: What does it mean to be immune  to White Walkers? Does it mean that Jon's body will be invulnerable to any weapon which White Walker would try to use against him?

Comment: It's more about not making  him one of them or their army (wights).

Comment: No one knows... **YET**... There's nothing wrong with asking a question that can not yet be answered. That does **not** make it "opinion based".

Comment: @AnkitSharma You realize that's a valid answer that should go as an actual answer, not a comment? 'We don't know' can be a valid answer given some explanation as to why we don't know..

Comment: What do you mean "immune"? Do you mean that if Jon dies again he will not be able to raised as a member of the army of the dead? White Walkers still use physical means (weapons) to kill. So you might be asking since Jon is now "infused with fire" that the ice swords the White Walkers will be ineffective against Jon?

Answer (score 5):

We can only speculate but I would say that it is unlikely. George R.R.Martin has said that he does not like the idea of bringing people back to life better than before. He wants them to be alittle worse for wear.

If what the Red Priests say can be trusted, a fire burns inside everyone that gives them life. When they die the fire goes out. When Red Priests bring people back to life, all they are doing is reigniting the flame of life within them, it's not something the resurrected person didn't have before. When we see Thoros of Myr praying over Beric Dondarrion's body, he says "His flame has been exstinguished, restore it." If anything the flame of life would be burning lower than before, making Jon more susceptible to the White Walker, if that's even possible. So the simple answer is no. Jon has not gained anything from his experience, his inner fire was always there and we have seen that it doesn't protect other people from the White Walkers. Jon's inner flame is likely even weaker than it was before.

Answer (score 3):

**We don't know.**

The TV series has not explored this yet, and Jon's resurrection has yet to occur in the books.

While this may be addressed in forthcoming seasons, at this stage any other answer would be conjecture.